# Can't get complete array through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, laravel

*JavaScript:*

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')},
    method: 'POST',
    url: "{{URL::to('/person/mission/punch/import')}}",
    data: {
        form_year: selected_year,
        forms: form.data
    },
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

I saw **Chorme -> Network -> Header -> Form Data**.

Here has Complete Array.

*my PHP:*

```
dd($_POST['forms']);
```

Can't dump complete Array(). I use Laravel.

Comment: whats the definition of `form` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your index value is not correct it must be a valid data or json object

```
data: {
    form_year: selected_year,
    forms: $("#formID").serializeObject();
},
```

I created a jquery function it convert serialized form data into a json object

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Javascript

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$.ajax({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')},
    method: 'POST',
    url: "{{URL::to('/person/mission/punch/import')}}",
    data: {
        form_year: selected_year,
        forms: $("form").serializeObject();
    },
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```